# Cannot turn off zooming when using TeeCharts on Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

I am using TeeCharts on Monotouch and zooming can only be turned off if I use:

```
chart.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyles.Manual;
```

But if I use the manual option I have rendering issues when using it on the device.
If I just try to turn zooming off when I switch `ZoomScrollStyle` to auto and use:

```
chart.Chart.Zoom.Allow = false;
```

nothing happens.

**UPDATE:** I figured out that if the View3D is on everything is working but when I am working  in a 2D environment the zoom option is always on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, there are some different ZoomScrollStyles and ZoomStyles options. These options are explained in the "Tutorial 8 - TeeChart NET for iOS Applications", "API changes specific to TeeChart .NET for iOS" section. And also in the "Tutorial 10- Zoom and Scroll".

The Automatic ZoomScrollStyle is set by default. This style uses the iOS standard technique for zoom and scroll, but this is not supported for all series types, and only in 2D mode.

The Manual ZoomScrollStyle does the zoom by redrawing the chart, thus it's slower (we’ll try to improve this feature for future releases).

The dragging functionality works in both ZoomScrollStyles, and also both in 2D and 3D.

Steema Support.

Comment: Just one question. Where is the API changes specific to TeeChart .NET for iOS article? Tried to google it and did't find it anywhere.

Comment: Find the tutorials (TeeChartNETforiOSTutorials.chm file) in the docs folder in your installation. Download the latest version available if your version doesn't contain them. The "API changes specific to TeeChart .NET for iOS" is a section in the Tutorial 8.